# Looking to have new surface card at same position as previous surface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a scrimmed surface that appears when the user clicks on a certain card on a lazylist to change the name of that card, how would I go about putting the textbox on the new surface over the selected card on the lazy-list surface?

I'll be honest I'm not even sure where to start. I just got the state-hoisting working and the surface to appear with the textbox but it stays at the top of the screen. With how my current list is formatted it perfectly covers the first card in the lazylist but thats the only time it works lol

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestHoistngTheme {
              
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    var names = (1..50).map { fullName("User $it") }
                    MyScreen(names = names)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HelloContent(name: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit, makeNull: () -> Unit) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Card() {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = name,
                onValueChange = onNameChange,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
                )
    }
}

data class fullName(
    var name: String,
)

@Composable
fun MyScreen(names: List<fullName>) {
    var selected by remember {
        mutableStateOf<fullName?>(null)
    }


        LazyColumn(
            Modifier.
                    fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(names) { _, fullName ->
                Text(
                    text = fullName.name,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            selected = fullName
                        }
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    if(selected != null){
        Surface(color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.6f)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.clickable{selected = null}) {
                selected?.let { it ->
                    var name by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(selected!!.name) }
                    HelloContent(name = name,
                        onNameChange = {
                        selected!!.name = it
                        name = it
                    }) { selected = null }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```